# $match and update a certain key in object after $unwind in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents like the following one:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc027d38da295b969eca67c"), 
    "emp_no" : 10031, 
    "salaries" : [
        {
            "salary" : 40000, 
            "from_date" : "1991-09-01", 
            "to_date" : "1992-08-31"
        }, 
        {
            "salary" : 40859, 
            "from_date" : "1992-08-31", 
            "to_date" : "1993-08-31"
        }, 
        {
            "salary" : 41881, 
            "from_date" : "1993-08-31", 
            "to_date" : "1994-08-31"
        }
    ]
}
```

As a goal I need to increment `salary` by 1000 for every object that has `from_date` key in a range of *1985-01-01* - *1985-12-31*. 
So far i came up with this query:

```
db.emp_salaries.aggregate( [
  { $unwind: "$salaries" },
  { $match: {
    "salaries.from_date": {$gte: "1985-01-01"},
    "salaries.from_date": {$lte: "1985-12-13"},
  } }
] )
```

but i can't target `from_date` key this way. I have no idea how to do this. This `$match` seems to be totally ignored. I've heard about an operator which can automatically target such a key regardless of its position from the beginning of an object, but couldn't find it back.
How do I target this key and perform an update on `salary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *filtered positional operator* `$[<identifier>]` identifies the array elements that match the `arrayFilters` conditions for an *update operation*. The following query will update the sub-document fields in the array with the matching condition.

```
db.arr_upd.updateMany(
    { },
    { $inc: { "salaries.$[elem].salary" : 1000 } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { $and: [ { "elem.from_date": { $gte: "1991-09-01" } },  { "elem.from_date": { $lte: "1992-08-31" } } ] } ] }
)
```

This will update the first two elements' `salary` values to `41000` and `41859`, respectively (for the example document shown in the question post).

Comment: Thank you, this works :) can you please explain in a few simple words how does arrayFilters work? I checked out [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) but I still don't understand how it worked here. Also, this _filter positional operator_ works like some kind of "pointer" which you use to refer to the array elements, right?

Comment: See these [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#specify-arrayfilters-for-an-array-update-operations) from the docs. Every element in the array is checked with the condition in the _arrayFIelds_ and is updated (to the field and value within the _update_, when a match happens. It is a quirky syntax; one can understand with some practice.

Comment: Also see this: [$[<identifier>](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ISODate instead of regular strings for the date field. 
It probably compare it by it's string value and not as date

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using a shell command.

```
db.emp_salaries.updateMany({
  'salaries.from_date': {
     $gte: '1985-01-01', 
     $lte: '1985-12-13'
   }
}, 
{
  $inc: {'salaries.$.salary': 1000} 
})
```

Comment: I couldn't get through `'salaries.from_date'` condition :( Maybe that's because there are no objects directly inside the `salaries` but they are inside the array?