# How to update many records at once in a document with deferent values from array input in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Product Order Relationship like **transfers in Shopify** if I want to update the details of order and products, which could be there values like price and quantity has been changed from client side and request is coming to server-side like this

```
{
  "id": "5dca5e935d5f0e3ba6486ee0",
  "input": {
    "supplier": "5ccb25033760713f4d9dbd1c",
    "deliverTo": "5c87d26cdee9297ceafbff53",
    "deliveryDue": "2019-03-12",
    "invoiceNumber": "22A51",
    "items": [{
      "_id": "5dca5e935d5f0e3ba6486ee1",
      "productId": "5d58d81e9d1f200356d013af",
      "quantity": "22",
      "price": "121"
    },
      {
      "_id": "5dca5e935d5f0e3ba6486ee2",
      "productId": "5d58d81e9d1f200356d013af",
      "quantity": "56",
      "price": "12"
    }

    ]
    }
}
```

Here I want to update the items from request in database so I need to loop through  `items` in request object and update one by one don't you think it increase database call and it raises performance issue .

Code (that is tried):

```
request.items.forEach( (item) => { 
                           OrderItem.update( { _id: item._id }, 
                                             { $set: { quantity: item.quantity, price: item.price } } ) 
                      } )
```

Comment: See this post which does similar operation: [updates array elements based on element sub-document field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856417/match-and-update-a-certain-key-in-object-after-unwind-in-mongodb/58857960#58857960)

Comment: Please post some sample code or pseudo-code you had tried.

Comment: @prasad_ ```request.items.forEach((item) => { OrderItem.update({_id: item._id}, { $set: { quantity: item.quantity, price: item.price } })  })```

Comment: what about initializeUnorderedBulkOp and doing it with bulk way